# Is there a simple way to position subtitles below the HLML5 video?

Tags: video, html5-video

I tried searching for an answer but could not find a viable one.

**Is there a simple way to position the subtitles below the HLML5 video frame?**

In other words, I do not want the subtitles / captions to appear inside the video frame itself. I want them to appear approximately 1/2 inch below the video frame.

Currently the subtitles are in a standard .srt file, but I can adapt the subtitles to a method that works for this.

I am also currently using HTML `<video>` element.

The image below represents what I want to accomplish.

There is a video example here [Example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/#toc-notjustvideo) by Sam Dutton, but the code he references to Eric Bidelman is a dead link.

On the example page Sam Dutton shows snippets of code, but I can make anything out of it.

Play the example video on the example page to see what I am talking about.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Example of Subtitles / Captions below the video frame]

Comment: with the default `<video>` sadly no, you would have to use a 3rd party player that supports over-riding the position of that element (I think plyr.io for instance allows that, but haven't tried)

Comment: I looked at plyr.io, but could not see a way to do it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I looks like I am answering my own question.

Since searching the web for a possible solution yielded no viable results, I went back and spent a few hours working on the video example on Sam Dutton's page.

From this, I was able to put together a simplified HTML5 video solution that can reposition the subtitles above or below the video as shown the posted image above.

Below is the complete HTML code for **two solutions**.

(1) Simplified Solution - A minimum code solution that works well.

(2) Full Solution - Yields the same results found on Sam Dutton's page.

The solutions include **.webm** video and **.vtt** subtitle files. **MP4** video and **.srt** subtitles work too.

**Note:** The HTML code has to reside on a web server to run properly. It does not function properly on a non-server type local machine. Just save the code in an HTML file (.html) and upload it to a web server.

Below is the Debug Security notice presented when trying to open the .html file locally within the Chrome browser:

```
 *Unsafe attempt to load URL https://www....../subtitles.vtt from frame with
 URL http://www........video.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.*
```

I hope this helps if you are looking for a similar solution.

Sam

---

**(1) Simplified Solution - A minimum code solution that works well.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#video_container {max-width:400px; margin:auto; border:1px solid #404040;}
video {max-width:100%; outline:none;}
div#video {text-align:center;}
div#video video {margin:0;}
div#video > div {margin-top:5px; text-align:center; color:#404040; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:1.0em;}
//-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="video_container">
<div id="video">
  <video width="400px" controls>
    <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    <track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="subtitles.vtt" default>
  </video>
  <div>subtitle position</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
(function(){
var video = document.querySelector('div#video video');
var span1 = document.querySelector('div#video > div');
span1.innerHTML = '';
if (!video.textTracks) return;

var track = video.textTracks[0];
track.mode = 'hidden';
var idx = 0;

track.oncuechange = function(e) {
  var cue = this.activeCues[0];
  if (cue) {
    if (idx >= 0) {
      span1.classList.remove('on');
      span1.innerHTML = '';
      span1.appendChild(cue.getCueAsHTML());
      span1.classList.add('on');
    }
    idx = ++idx % 2;
  }
};
})();
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**(2) Full Solution - Yields the same results found on Sam Dutton's page.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
video {max-width: 100%; outline: none;}

div#video video {margin: 0;}
div#video {text-align: center;}

div#video > div {
margin-top: 2em;
text-align: center;
-webkit-perspective: 800;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-perspective: 800;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-perspective: 800;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-perspective: 800;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div#video > div > div:last-child {position:relative; top:-36px;} /* position subtitle below video */

div#video > div > div {
color: black;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
height:  25px;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
-moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
-o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
-o-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
-ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

div#video > div > div.on {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
-moz-transform: rotateX(0);
-o-transform: rotateX(0);
-ms-transform: rotateX(0);
}

.trackNotSupported {display: none;}
.trackNotSupported.show {display: block;}
.warningMessage {color: red;
}

//-->
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="video">
  <video width="400px" controls>
    <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    <track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="subtitles.vtt" default>
  </video>
  <div><div>subtitle line 1</div><div>subtitle line 2</div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
(function(){
var video = document.querySelector('div#video video');
var span1 = document.querySelector('div#video > div :first-child');
var span2 = document.querySelector('div#video > div :last-of-type');

if (!video.textTracks) return;

var track = video.textTracks[0];
track.mode = 'hidden';
var idx = 0;

track.oncuechange = function(e) {
  var cue = this.activeCues[0];
  if (cue) {
    if (idx == 0) {
      span2.className = '';
      span1.classList.remove('on');
      span1.innerHTML = '';
      span1.appendChild(cue.getCueAsHTML());
      span1.classList.add('on');
    } else {
      span1.className = '';
      span2.classList.remove('on');
      span2.innerHTML = '';
      span2.appendChild(cue.getCueAsHTML());
      span2.classList.add('on');
    }
    idx = ++idx % 2;
  }
};
})();
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```